# Edit specific data in yaml file without editing the whole yaml file in Python

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have the following YAML file:

```
yaml:
  type: bus
  format-version: 1.0.0
main:
  sub:

    test_data1:
      version: 0.0.20
      url:
        repo: artifactory_1

    test_data2:
      version: 0.1.8
      url:
        repo: artifactory_2
```

Whenever I try to make a change in 'test_data1-version' I do the following:

```
import ruamel.yaml
import yaml

def read_yaml(file_path: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
with open(file_path) as file1:
    yaml_data = yaml.full_load(file1)
    return yaml_data

def write_yaml(file_path: str, data: Dict[str, Any]):
with open(file_path, 'w') as file3:
    yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
    yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
    yaml.default_flow_style= False
    yaml.dump(data, file3)
```

I read the yaml file, make the change in the version number from '0.0.20' to '1.0.0' and use the write function to write the edited data back to yaml file. When I do this, I end up with a yaml file with completely different format(below shown whitespaces missing).

```
yaml:
  type: bus
  format-version: 1.0.0
main:
  sub:
    test_data1:
      version: 1.0.0
      url:
        repo: artifactory_1
    test_data2:
      version: 0.1.8
      url:
        repo: artifactory_2
```

Anyone with any ideas on how not to edit the format of the whole file, rather just edit the specific data required.

Comment: I think having newlines with whitespaces in .yaml files is not the standardized format. Why would you want to have those newlines with whitespaces in the file?

Comment: @Oivalf please give a reference to the standardized format you are writing about. The YAML specifications have several different formatting in their examples, so as far as I was aware, there is no such standardized format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple script that does the whitepsaces.

```
file_1 = open('wrong_formated.yaml', 'r')
Lines = file_1.readlines()
file_2 = open('new_yaml.yaml', 'w')

indent_for_element_with_new_lines = 4

for line in Lines:
    print(line)
    if line.startswith(' ' * indent_for_element_with_new_lines) and line[5] != ' ':
        file_2.writelines('\n')
    file_2.writelines(line)
```

But it requires that all the elements with whitespaces before have the same indent. And no other element has that indent.

Comment: It is easy to create invalid YAML this way, of course depening on the changes you make. Much better to use a proper YAML loader/dumper.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me why you use the outdated PyYAML to load your data.
If you use `ruamel.yaml` for that as well you can round-trip the input without a problem.

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path

in_file = Path('input.yaml')


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(in_file)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
yaml:
  type: bus
  format-version: 1.0.0
main:
  sub:

    test_data1:
      version: 0.0.20
      url:
        repo: artifactory_1

    test_data2:
      version: 0.1.8
      url:
        repo: artifactory_2
```

You don't have to use `yaml.default_flow_style` unless you add additional dicts or lists,
as it doesn't affect mappings/sequences loaded with `ruamel.yaml`.

Comment: This gives out the same formatted output as mentioned in the question

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, because the output I show is not the same your output and captured from running the program before that.

Comment: Yes you were right. I was unknowingly using yaml.full_load() and not ruamel.yaml.load(). It works now.